# REACT Multiple Registration

Tags: forms, reactjs, registration

I have a problem with React, so I created script and it doesn't work.

This should:

1. Render first state step (it's working) (Component First)
2. Here is error, it don't see default values.(name & email
3. After click Save And Continue it should save files to data.
4. And going to next steps in cases.

The error is

bundle.js:34147 Uncaught ReferenceError: email is not defined

```
 function send(e){
  e.preventDefault()
}




function nextStep(){
  this.setState({
    step:this.state.step + 1
  })
}

function nextStep(){
  this.setState({
    step:this.state.step - 1
  })
}


function saveAndContinue(e) {

  e.preventDefault()
  // Get values via this.refs
  var data = {
    name     : this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value,
    email    : this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value,
  }

  this.props.saveValues(data)
  this.props.nextStep()
};



var fieldValues = [
   name     : null,
   email    : null,
];


function saveValues(fields) {
    return (
        fieldValues = Object.assign({}, fieldValues, fields)
    );
}


class Registration extends React.Component{

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
      step:1
    }
  }

    render() {
        switch (this.state.step) {
            case 1:
            return <First fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues} />
            case 2:
            return <Two fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues}/>
            case 3:
            return <Third fieldValues={fieldValues}
                            nextStep={this.nextStep}
                            previousStep={this.previousStep}
                            saveValues={this.saveValues}/>
            case 4:
            return <Success fieldValues={fieldValues} />
        }
    }
}



class First extends React.Component{



  render(){
    return(
      <form onSubmit ={send}>
            <div className="group">
                  <input className="text" type="text" ref="name" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.name}/>
                  <span className="highlight"></span>
                  <span className="bar"></span>
                  <label>Write Name</label>
            </div>
            <div className="group">
                 <input className="text" type="email" ref="email" defaultValue={this.props.fieldValues.email} />
                 <span className="highlight"></span>
                 <span className="bar"></span>
                 <label>Write Your Mail</label>
            </div>
           <button onClick={this.saveAndContinue}>Save and Continue</button>
      </form>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Two, Third and Success classes in your code, so I'm assuming they are similar to the First class.

- A global function doesn't need `this` keyword. But in this case, you have to put `saveAndContinue` inside `First` class if it need to access the state.
- In React, normally you don't have to set default value for input.
  Link the input value to the state, and then `setState` in `onChange` event.
  The string in `placeholder` is shown when the state is empty.

The code below shows how to work with input tag in React:

```js
<input
  value={this.state.inputValue}
  onChange={e => {
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }}
  type="text"
  placeholder="default value"
/>
```

Note that the state will updates `onChange` rather than click the save button.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you for information:

I drop this code, and written new.

Thank for advices it's very helpful.